# Save method override and exceptions management

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, custom-exceptions

Currently, I am developing an application which domain model should prevent objects duplication according the equality or not of some object fields.

So, I am thinking to handle this comparison on the save method of the class: if some existing object has some properties equal to the object to be saved, the save should be prevented.

I am thinking to deal this situation with an Exceptions, which would be thrown and catched in the action, in order to present a message to the user, if necessary. Unfortunately, my knowledge about Exceptions is not quite good and more: would be this solution the most adequate?

The ORM which I am using is Doctrine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create an unique index on multiple columns in your schema: This is an example taken from [Doctrine's manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/defining-models%3aindexes%3aindex-options):

```
MultipleIndexTest:
  columns:
    name: string
    code: string
    age: integer
  indexes:
    myindex:
      fields:
        name:
          sorting: ASC
          length: 10
        code: -
      type: unique
```

Comment: Hi! Honestly, I do not considered the approach you mentioned, but it seems also valid. I only have one doubt: how can I set proper messages to the user, with the solution you suggested, it is not necessary to handle with the controller and view?

Comment: Doctrine will throw an exception that you can handle with a try-catch block.